# Deleted entry from strings.xml is getting displayed

Tags: android, xml, localization

My App supports different languages and English is the default one and saved in strings.xml, and according to [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/)

```
If the supported language strings.xml misses any string value, android always loads the missing strings from default strings.xml file i.e values/strings.xml

So it is mandatory that the default stings.xml file should contains all the string values that app uses. Other wise the app will crash with Force Close error.
```

So, i set the system language locale to Deutsch an and deleted the following entry from strings.xml of both of English and Deutsch

```
<string name="activity_login_validate_button" formatted="false">Login</string>
```

and when I run the App, I expected it to crash as stated earlier in the quoted text, but it runs normally without a crash.

Would anyone please explain how the App displayed the word "Login" normally despite it is deleted from the strings.xml of English"default" and Deutsch?

Note:string.xml of other languages contains complete string values

Answer (score 1):

Once you entered string and run the project, all string values can stored in background. To remove that just uninstall previously installed app and clean your project and run again. All removed values are cleaned.